# Android Studio can't download update

Tags: android, android-studio

So after a while of not using Android Studio, decided to come back and update to version 1.0, but it gets stuck downloading the file.

[Image to update status](http://i.gyazo.com/ed1e967a5b48626976b3e7c5d0f85f7f.png)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: From the image, we can know that you need to install 0.x version to 1.x first. After that, you need to download the patch to update this software (3MB). The 1.x installer is the same size with new installer of Android Studio.It's better for you to download the new version of Android Studio (828.11MB only) from this [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem prior to Android Studio 1.0.x.check [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78129).So for any versions before this.Downloading the package again solves the issue.I have not faced issues applying patches from 1.0.0 to 1.0.2 and onwards.

**EDIT**:suggested solutions include running Android Studio with admin rights.But that never seemed to work for me either.